# Get data from sub array in another variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have this array :

```
[
   0 => {
     id: 1,
     name: 'Test 1',
     clients: [
        0 => {
          id: 100,
          name: 'Client 1'
        }
     ]
   },
   1 => {
     id: 2,
     name: 'Test 2',
     clients: [
         0 => {
            id: 101,
            name: 'Client 2'
         }
     ]
   }
]
```

What's the best way, and the short one to get all subarray data in my case all `clients` :

```
[
    0 => {
        id: 100,
        name: 'Client 1'
    },
    1 => {
        id: 101,
        client: 'Client 2'
    }
]
```

Thx in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: Where is your attempt to solve the problem?

Comment: Your question appears to be too broad for SO and asking for `the best way` is opiniated and off-topic here. To improve your queston, consider adding the following information: What have you tried so far? Where do you have problems accomplishing your task?

Comment: Can you also please modify your arrays so that they don't throw a syntax error

Comment: `0 => {...}` is not valid. `=>` is for defining arrow functions, but `0` and `1` aren't valid parameter names.

Comment: I think you mean `[{ ... }, { ... }]` with no `0=>` and `1=>`

Comment: looks a bit like php

Comment: The method [`flatmap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) should be useful for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reduce and inside the callback you can use the `concat` to create the new array

```js
let data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Test 1',
    clients: [{
      id: 100,
      name: 'Client 1'
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Test 2',
    clients: [{
      id: 101,
      name: 'Client 2'
    }]
  }
]
let newData = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  return acc.concat(curr.clients)
}, []);
console.log(newData)
```